# About hamburger menu style in UWP project

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I want to know how to achieve the same style of the hamburger menu button in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2haj.jpg) (blue rectangle in left menu) in my UWP project by using XAML.

I already know how to achieve this using Template 10, but now I want to design it by myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at Template10. It is quite easy to achieve this. you'll need a `SplitView` to achieve this.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Template10 source code](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Controls/HamburgerMenu.xaml) to get an idea on how it's done?

Answer (score 1):

The hamburger menu is just a regular button with the hamburger icon.
You can easily create your own like:

```
<Button x:Name="navigationMenu" 
        Style="{StaticResource NavigationMenuButton}" 
        Command="{x:Bind ShowHideNavigationMenuCommand}" />
```

With the following style which is just the default button style with a few minor changes:

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationMenuButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonSmallStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TitleBarForegroundColor}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE700;" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemColorHighlightHighColor}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemColorHighlightColor}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SubtleColor}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the UWP Community toolkit:
http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/HamburgerMenu/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/